# Can not install Phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Cant install phpmyadmin on kali linux rolling on virtualbox after following a 2019 tutorial on youtube,

Tried

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

(which was all the tutor done)

Package phpmyadmin is not available, but is referred to by another package.

`apt-cache policy phpmyadmin` says there is no candidate.

Unless phpmyadmin has a repository i have not added then i am confused as the tutorial i watched and followed was to the letter.

/etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

Comment: Thanks for asking this. Finally got my phpmyadmin up and running.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `phpmyadmin` is not in the kali repositories, but you can use those of debian.

Add these repositories to your `etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main
```

Save the file, then run the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

EDITS: phpmyadmin now is in the default repository in the latest kali versions

Comment: I seem to get a few errors on the update line, it says there is no public key. [https://snipboard.io/PA0cdL.jpg]

Comment: files is at /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: This fixed my issue though on Debian 10 Digital Ocean droplet. Thanks a million.

Comment: @JFed-9 If it says: `GPG error: <REPO>: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY <PUBKEY>`, you can always do following: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <PUBKEY>` where PUBKEY is the KEY from the Error line.

Comment: @JFed-9 or simply `sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated` - but its a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Repository which should be in your "/etc/apt/sources.list":

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Next, run the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin -y
$ sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin  /var/www/html
$ sudo service mysql start
$ sudo service apache2 start
```

Finally, start your favorite browser and type:

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer ever I know and it is a youtube video .
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLwQMBpUPQs

Answer (score 0):

Debian replaced `phpmyadmin` in the LAMP stack with `phpliteadmin`.

Comment: Does it work for MySql databases??